# System randomly reboots after GNOME session failure (or something else)

Tags: gnome, 20.04

My Ubuntu 20.04.1 reboots out of the blue, sometimes seconds after login, sometimes after I'd started some work. I'm thinking it's related to the GNOME session failure. I found this in `var/sys/log` just before it happens:

```
Jan 13 20:28:18 localhost gnome-session[1810]: gnome-session-binary[1810]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' failed to register before timeout
Jan 13 20:28:18 localhost gnome-session-binary[1810]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' failed to register before timeout
Jan 13 20:28:18 localhost gnome-session-binary[1810]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Jan 13 20:28:18 localhost gnome-session[1810]: gnome-session-binary[1810]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan 13 20:28:18 localhost gnome-session-binary[1810]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan 13 20:28:18 localhost gnome-shell[1942]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jan 13 20:28:18 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2125]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
    
### Starts to kill, stop and close services ###
    
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1596]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1596]: systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1596]: Finished Exit the Session.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1596]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1]: user@121.service: Succeeded.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 121.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/121...
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[2373]: run-user-121.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1]: run-user-121.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@121.service: Succeeded.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/121.
Jan 13 20:28:28 localhost systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 121.
Jan 13 20:28:32 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Jan 13 20:28:46 localhost systemd[1]: Received SIGINT.
Jan 13 20:28:46 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Session 2 of user @#$%.
Jan 13 20:28:46 localhost gnome-shell[2733]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
```

Am I correct? I've tried reinstalling gnome-shell, didn't help. Is there any way to fix it other than reinstalling the OS from scratch?